Unable to rename copied geodatabase
I have an existing script that copies a geodatabase to another location and renames it. It uses arcpy and os libraries to do it.
copy_from = r"C:\test.gdb"
copy_to = r"D:\test.gdb"
rename_to = r"D:\test_renamed.gdb"

arcpy.env.overwriteoutput = True
arcpy.Copy_management(copy_from, copy_to)
os.rename(copy_to, rename_to)

However, while renaming I am getting PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied. I have verified that the user running the script has full access. I am able to temporarily fix the issue by using os.copytree instead of the arcpy function but I don't know why it is giving that error.
I have tried running Copy_management(copy_from, rename_to) as well but that gives a 000260: Failed to copy error.
EDIT:
System Specifications
Hardware - Intel Xeon 6248R, 128 GB RAM
OS - Windows Server 2019
Python Version - 2.7.18

Based on the version of python I assume you are running ArcMap, not ArcPro? My only suggestion is try running your script on another machine that is not running a server version of windows?

@Hornbydd Yes. For some reason, it is working on another (QA) server where the same script is deployed

Do not use the OS module to rename the geodatabase, use the rename tool instead. You are getting file locking occurring as you have accessed the geodatabase via arcpy.

I tried this too but it is throwing - ERROR 999999 - Error executing function. General function failure

That would indicate the source of your problem lies elsewhere and without further details will be impossible to solve.

Could you indicate what kind of problem it might be?

Not really there is not enough detail in your question. You say nothing about your system setup for a start. Edit your question and add that.

Sure. I have added them
